# Why Oracle crash in .net standard of UWP but winform not?

Tags: oracle, uwp, .net-standard

I make a UWP program and I have to get data from a Oracle database of my customer. My customer gave me a dll which he made. I tried and found that made by .net framework of 4.6.2 so that UWP do not support it. I suggested him rewrite the dll by UWP, but he refused that. So I have to find a way to make it works in UWP.
I googled and found that if I make a .net standard dll for the bridge between UWP and .net framework that I can make it works in UWP.
Finally, I made a .net standard dll, in the .net standard I reference the dll my customer gave.
But after I debugged my .net standard dll, all code I wrote works without error, but the dll my customer gave threw an error:

```
"The type initializer for 'OracleInternal.Common.ProviderConfig' threw an exception."
```

I wonder if there is something wrong with the dll of my customer. However,it is so strange that if I reference his dll in winform, all is OK, but only in .net standard it crashed. What's more, the code what I wrote in winform/.net standard is the same, only declare a class and run a void, just two-line code.  
My customer knows nothing about UWP and I also know nothing about Oracle.I don't want rewrite whole project by WPF just for this, that's such a huge work!
Would you please teach me what's wrong with that and how to solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use Entity Framework Core which support Oracle? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/

Comment: @Ashiq Thanks for telling me about this, but it is a little different about this. The Entity Framework Core just Read/Write the database directly, but the customer does not want me to do this, they wrote a dll and let me reference the dll to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if there is something wrong with the dll of my customer.

In short, there's no wrong in your customer's .net framework dll. You just misunderstood the .NET Standard. Your .NET Standard library worked in winform, that's because your .NET Standard library adds reference to your customer's .net framework dll. This .net framewrok dll works well in .net framework applications, but it doesn't mean that the APIs in the .net framework dll are supported in UWP, even if you've used your .NET Standard library to wrap it. I suggested that you could read [Introducing .NET Standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/) for more detailed information.

For your question, if your customer does not want to rewrite their dll and you're also not able to write a library to make it work in UWP. You could make a [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/basic-wcf-programming). In WCF, you could directly add reference to your customer's dll. Then, you could use this WCF service in your UWP directly.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I created WCF Service Library as you said and referenced it. However, Visual Studio reports an error that "A reference to 'CustomWCF.dll" could not be added. The project target '.NetCore' while the file reference targets '.NetFramework'. This is not a supported scenario." It seems that WCF is still.net framework but not .net core which UWP support.

Comment: @102425074 I meant that you could make a WCF service application and then you could host this WCF service application in your service. In your UWP app, you could add this service reference. See [Hosting in Internet Information Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/hosting-in-internet-information-services)